# Wordpress and private / member-only section, personalization etc. Is it possible?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress

Before diving into Wordpress just wanted to see if it is possible to have private section of website, where-in content specific to user is made available, for consumption by the viewer only, or her/his invited members, and not automatically available for all members. What are the ways in which I could personalize the member's experience ?

Is this possible using some WP-plugin, or would it require extensive programmatic changes ? If so, is my requirement in some sort of fundamental contradiction with WP philosophy/design, and thus it is not a good idea to proceed with WP?

My inclination towards WP is it's power and popularity as a CMS, with a plethora of plugins, s.t. in this particular project of mine, where time is the thing in shortest supply (well, after money), I am hoping to get some leverage. Another very important reason is that I am not very familiar designing web-applications, portals etc.

Comment: Wordpress does not offer invites out of the box. Everything is possible with wordpress (but changing the application design) by using a plugin or introducing the changes to the code-base that gives you what you want (but I think you're looking for some ready-made solution of which I doesn't know one for your case).

Comment: Thanks @hakre. "Everything is possible with Wordpress", is something I really like about it, but is also something which keeps the scope open and thus risky, because I am not sure what I am getting into. So, given my situation, indeed, I'd prefer the Plugin approach, if possible. The other extreme would be to stick to PHP or one of the other PHP-Frameworks.  As for the part regarding invites, is it to invite new members ? If so, I am happy to manage it externally.

Comment: Yeah, its more a comment than a real answer. I would keep the requirements simple and then take a look for existing plugins. You might just need to add one plugin of your own additionally to get things in order. Having stuff in a plugin is actually helpful, but as you wrote it does not solve the well known wordpress upgrade problems because of it's broad design. However having the own code inside a plugin is better than hacking the core and you can do pretty much already. However getting the "family tree" of invites, you should think about which depth you need and that data stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic installation of wordpress can restrict posts and pages to specific user roles and/or password protect them.

By adding more than the standard 5 user roles or duplicating a certain role to transform their function from role to essentially user groups you can extend those capabilities.

As you said there is a plethora of plugins and some of those also cater to user and user role management. Check out [this article](http://freelancefolder.com/unleash-the-power-of-wordpress-using-plugin-combos/) on extending wordpress with plugin combos and especially check the last section titled "Create Your Own Custom Membership Site". Apart from the 4 plugins mentioned there (which all are awesome) you can search for similar plugins in the [wordpress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/). To really be able to judge the power and suitability of a plugin you need to have a wp installation ready and test yourself.

Comment: As an aside, this question might have been better asked at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_Pille. My exposure to WP is limited as a user (and admin for my own blog), apart from admin for a domain, which I rarely use. So, while it might be a stupid question, but is there are programmatic way to add user-roles beyond the 5 ? I expect to be able to host upto 20-25K users, and if I understood the logic, might need as many user-roles. Is that practical / feasible ? Wasn't aware that such a SE site exists, so I guess I should continue rest of the discussion there.

Comment: @Mod, is it possible to move this question to wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I was thinking doubling to quadrupling user roles. Several thousand roles is definitely **not** feasible. I've never tested beyond that - it might be possible that wp could theoretically handle that many, but it would beyond the shadow of a doubt not be practical or manageable at all. WP can easily handle that many users though, that I can guarantee. I don't know of an existing "invite-plugin" or code example, you'd have to write a plugin yourself.

Comment: I haven't given this in-depth thought, but an approach would be to work with the unique user ID form the _wp_users_ table and create a new database table with the invites (bind invited users ID to the invitees ID) and write a function that queries that before displaying private posts and pages.